# Is there a way to search for a specific <div> in an HTML comment using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to extract a comment from the `HTML` of a site and parse though it like regular `HTML` to find specific `tags`.

My current code is:

```py
website_url = requests.get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/OAK/2019.shtml").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
appearances = comments.find("div", {"id": "div_appearances"})
for comment in comments:
    appearances = comment.find("div", {"id": "div_appearances"})
    print(appearances)
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\almar\Desktop\testesrseraseras.py", line 13, in <module>
    appearances = comment.find("div", {"id": "div_appearances"})
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

When I print out the parent element of the appearances `div` I can see that for some reason the `text` I want is inside a very large comment and I need to extract that, search for tags inside it using something like `div.find("element", {"id","id_name"})`, and print them out.

I'm looking for a table `Full-Season Roster & Games by Position` that is inside a comment, when I inspect element the table I want is outside the comment but when I try to print it out it is inside one.

Sorry for any errors I am very new!

Comment: Yes its posible, but clarify your question, read this please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Comments is a list, you have to iterate and find on each item if you need it

Comment: which comment you looking to extract ?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I try `for comment in comments:
    appearances = comment.find("div", {"id": "div_appearances"})
    print(appearances)` and get an error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\almar\Desktop\testesrseraseras.py", line 13, in <module>
    appearances = comment.find("div", {"id": "div_appearances"})
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method"

Comment: @CaptainFinn comments section is not for expanding the question. please edit the question and include all details !

Comment: @CaptainFinn check the below answer, there's 2 tables with the name of `Roster` which is `Current 40-Man Roster` and `Full-Season Roster & Games by Position` ! which one you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/OAK/2019.shtml")[0]

df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [View-Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/729047b99ff74af51305fb47b6afe82c/out.csv)

> UPDATE:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fteams%2FOAK%2F2019.shtml&div=div_appearances")

data = df[0][0:-1].iloc[:, :-1]

data.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/41b55db6426f87526580e47ffc56a7b6/out.csv)

Comment: That's what I want but that outputs the first table labeled "Team Batting". The one I want is the 4th one down labeled "Full-Season Roster & Games by Position". Is there a way to get that one?

Comment: @CaptainFinn alright so you have to include that in the question as well so that's make it easier for us to understand your target. anyway i will update my answer shortly for your desired target.

Comment: @CaptainFinn check my updated answer. feel free to accept the answer if it's solved your case By ticking the check mark beside the answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! Sorry for my poorly worded question.

Comment: @CaptainFinn you welcome. make sure to copy the last update as i enhanced the output.